# presentViewController without parent view disappearing

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I have a UIViewController, which on it - I use presentViewController to present a new window:

```
controller.view.frame = source;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];


[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_NORMAL_DURATION animations:^{

    controller.view.frame = target;


}completion:^(BOOL finished) {


}];
```

When I do that - the parent controller (self) disappears before the new controller (controller) appears. And it makes it ugly.

Is there a better way to implement it?
(I don't use NavigationControler in those ViewContollers)

Thanks.

Comment: What effect would you like to have happen instead?

Comment: i want the new controller to slide over the parent controller (self). Now - the parent disappear, and only then - the new one slides.

Answer (score 3):

From iOS7 there is the **modalPresentationStyle** property. 
Set it to one of this options: *UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen, UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext, UIModalPresentationCustom*

`modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;`

Answer (score 0):

do not present, just add a subview

```
controller.view.frame = source;
//[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];


[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_NORMAL_DURATION animations:^{

     controller.view.frame = target;

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the parent view controller won't react to ViewDidAppear, etc.

Comment: call them yourself. viewDidappear for example in completion block

Comment: yeah, it's an idea. isn't there a more elegant way?